# speed up pandas series.rolling.appy()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I need to compute product of all values within rolling windows for pandas series, ignore nan.

I am using pandas.Series.rolling.apply as current approach, but the speed is rather slow compare to built-in functions, I am working on huge dataframes therefore speed is my concern.

as a demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(range(100))
```

```
%timeit -n100 a.rolling(5).apply(np.nanprod,raw=True)
5.58 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -n100 a.rolling(5).mean()
236 µs ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the `apply()` is a lot slower compare to built-in `mean` function

1 is there a way to speed up the apply process

2 or is there a built-in product function for rolling window(ignore nan if possible)? Cant find it in docs

Comment: For lower overhead, try turning your Series into numpy arrays, and operating on those.

Comment: Why are you comparing `np.nanprod` with `.mean()`?

Comment: @jorijnsmit `%timeit -n100 a.rolling(5).apply(np.mean,raw=False)` 
`11.3 ms ± 59.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`, it is what happened in apply slow things down, not mean. I am comparing `np.nanprod` to `mean` since there is no built in product function, otherwise my entire question wont exist.

Comment: @J_H will try that, rolling function in numpy is not as intuitive as in pandas though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe to your problem is *as_strided* Numpy function.

To use it, define the following function:

```
def roll_win(a, win):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - win + 1, win)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

Then call *np.nanprod* on the result of this function:

```
np.nanprod(roll_win(a.values, 5), axis=1)
```

The difference is that the result is a *Numpy* 1-D array, without 4 initial *NaN*
values, but the speed should be significantly better.

Comment: this answer solved my problem, the missing values are easy to add and set to original pd.Series

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a [`.prod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) function which ignores NA/null values by default.